# Angular 2 HttpClient Delete collection

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, fork-join

I have a service that looks like this:

```
delete<T>(id: number): Observable<T> {
   return this.http.delete<T>(this.url + '/delete/' + id)
          //etc
          //etc
}
```

Now, I'd like to call this method from a `forEach` loop without exhausting the db.

In theory, I could try it recursively like this:

```
doDeletion(index){
    service.delete()
           .subscribe(success => doDeletion(++index), 
                      err => doDeletion(++index));
}
```

But, this does not seem the correct approach. Would the `forkJoin` property work for this? How can I wait before each call without killing the database?

Thanks

Comment: No. forkJoin would run them all in parallel - which I assume is not what you're looking for. If you have control over the service, I suggest adding a method to the service that takes a list of items to delete, and have the service manage the process.

Comment: Yeah that's what I imagined @GreyBeardedGeek. I really wanted to use the old back-end without lots of modification since I am rewriting the front from angular 1. But I guess it wont be possible...

Comment: check out mergeMap (a.k.a. flatMap), tutorial at https://medium.com/@w.dave.w/becoming-more-reactive-with-rxjs-flatmap-and-switchmap-ccd3fb7b67fa

Comment: Can you change the backend service you are calling? With your current implementation, you are sending a dedicated request for each item you want to delete. This can become slow and causes a lot of traffic. If you want to delete your table completely, you could just create a "delete-all" service and fire a single SQL-Statement which deletes every entry at the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what input you expect but in general you can use `concatMap` that always waits until the current inner Observable completes:

```
const ids = [42, 24, 17, 1337];

Observable.from(ids)
  .concatMap(id => this.http.delete<T>(this.url + '/delete/' + id))
  .subscribe();
```

This will run each `delete()` after the previous one completed.

You mentioned that you might want to use recursion. For example if one `delete()` call returns another id that you want to `delete()` as well. This seems like a good job for the [`expand()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator that calls it's callback recursively:

```
Observable.of(id)
  .expand(id => id
    ? this.http.delete(this.url + '/delete/' + id).map(...) // map the response into another id
    : Observable.empty()
  )
  .subscribe();
```